# How to use sqlalchemy connectionpool to create sessions?

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I am having trouble using engine, connectionpool and sessions together. What I am trying to do is create an application wide engine and pool. Then create sessions from the connectionpool whenever i want. Below is my code sample:

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
engine = createEngine(pool_size, pool.QueuePool)
Session = sessionmaker()
def getConnection():
    try:
        return engine.connect()
    except:
        return False
mypool = pool.QueuePool(getConnection(), max_overflow, pool_size)
conn = mypool.connect()
session = Session(bind=conn)
result = session.query(Models.Features).all()
```

In the above code session.query() is giving error "error:'function' object has no attribute 'contextual_connect.

I have used the paragraph under the heading "Creating Ad-Hoc Session Objects with Alternate Arguments" in the page https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html as reference. Here is the code sample from the above page that I have used:

```
# at the module level, the global sessionmaker,
# bound to a specific Engine
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# later, some unit of code wants to create a
# Session that is bound to a specific Connection
conn = engine.connect()
session = Session(bind=conn)
```

In the above sample they are binding a session with a connection. I would like to know whether it is necessary to use connectionpool when using sessions. If yes, then how to create connectionpool and bind session with a connection obtained from the pool.

Comment: An honest question: why go all this trouble for something you'd pretty much achieve with just using the `engine` itself? In your example code it seems like you're basically adding a redundant `QueuePool` on top of the pool held by the `engine`. In addition this seems like a "typo" question, since the answer is "add brackets".

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have tried it with 'mypool.connect()', but did not work as well. As you have mentioned that I could do the pooling  just by using an engine, could you please explain? What I understood is, create an engine with pooling enabled and bind session with the engine, but not the connection. Is that correct? So behind it will use the connections from the pool. I will try this out and update. Thanks.

Comment: Well the thing was that you were calling a function where you shouldn't have, namely `pool.QueuePool(getConnection(), ...)`, and didn't call it where you should have: `conn = mypool.connect`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the engine.connect() method correctly. If you add the parentheses to it like so:

```
...
mypool = pool.QueuePool(getConnection(), max_overflow, pool_size)
conn = mypool.connect()
session = Session(bind=conn)
...
```

It should work properly.

Comment: I was trying to create a connection from the pool and to bind it with a session. I am not trying to bind the session with connection obtained from engine. In the reference that I have used, they are using connection object from engine, so I assumed that session can be bound to a connection obtained from pool as well.